# Windows Authentication, ASP.Net MVC Error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, authentication, windows-server-2008

I am moving an MVC application to a new server. The old server was Windows 2003, the new server is Windows 2012 R2.

The application uses windows authentication, then uses that user to make calls to SQL Server to retrieve data.

The application is still on MVC 1.0, built using Visual Studio 2008.

The application runs fine locally in visual studio. I then deployed the app to IIS7.5.
Now if I am using remote desktop to connect to the server, then run a browser on the server, the application runs fine.

The issue I am having is when I access the website from any other machine on the network.
Initially the mvc application loads and displays ok.
However when I click on any of the functions that call the SQL Database, I get a windows login popup box.

It looks like the credentials are not being passed through to sql server.

I am not sure why I am getting this login box, like I said it doesn't happen when I run locally in visual studio or locally directly on the server.

Even when this login box appears, and I enter my login credentials, the login fails.
Also after 3 login attempts the app pool crashes.

Does anyone have any ideas about why I am getting this login box?

Thanks

UPDATE: The SQL Server is on another box which has not changed.

UPDATE 2: I just discovered that if I set my Active Directory User ID and Password in the ASP.net Impersonation settings on IIS the application works ok from any machine.

Does this mean that Windows Auth is not getting my AD user ID and passing it through to SQL Server?

Comment: Sounds like you need to enable and use Sql Server Mixed Mode Auth : Windows Authnetication + Sql...

Comment: The database has not changed, it is on another box. Only the asp.net application moved to a new box. Like I said the application runs fine if I run it locally on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this weird behavior because the user under which `Application Pool` runs on your server doesn't not have enough permissions.

That user needs to have `NTFS` permissions.

If you change the user to `Local System` it will surely work. But this may not be allowed by your Security rules so you should check with your IT Manager first.

Comment: No this did make any difference, like I said the MVC app works fine, except when I call a page that calls the database and it only happens when I am not running locally.

Comment: How does the website connect to the database? windows auth?

Comment: So the problem is what I suspected initially. The user under which your AppPool runs doesn't have enough permissions.